# event.which value 'incorrect'

Tags: ascii, jquery, keypress, keycode

I get the "incorrect" value for event.which in chrome. for example:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    alert(e.which);
});
```

this code produces two alerts when I press the numpad '+' key, first says k, second says 107.
I want the first one to say + and the second, well the second doesn't matter too much, all I care about is getting the + symbol when typing the + key. Same for all mathematical operators, I am writing a calculator and need those symbols correct for the input elements. How do I do it?

---- WORKING ----
I must have done something wrong before, now it works great...

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 22: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/LHH9s/

Comment: interesting, it works in the fiddle, but not in my chrome. It does work in FF and IE though, I'll add this to the question. I need it to work in current versions of browsers at least, would also love to through in some backwards support. Having it work in a beta browser doesn't get me very far.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .keydown instead , i had few issues earlier with keypress behaviour in chrome which got resolved when I used keydown

Comment: Thanks mate, but it's the other way round with me. keydown didn't work, keypress did. I added the question to let viewers know the problem was solved.